# I obtained the following $g_{ij}$ for this metric. Do they make sense?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

I have the following problem:

Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R^n}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{n+k}$ be such that $(M,\varphi)$ is a differentiable manifold, where $M=\varphi(\mathbb{R}^n)\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+k}$. In other words, $\varphi$ is a global parametrization for $M$. Let $\langle,\rangle_{\varphi(0)}$ be the inner product in $T_{\varphi(0)}M$ such that $\{\frac{\partial}{\partial x_1}\vert_{\varphi(0)},\ldots,\frac{\partial}{\partial x_n}\vert_{\varphi(0)}\}$ is an orthonormal basis. Now, for $a\in \mathbb{R}^n$, we consider $L_a:M\rightarrow M$, defined by $L_a(\varphi(x))=\varphi(x+a)$. We choose $\langle,\rangle_{\varphi(a)}$ an inner product in $T_{\varphi(a)}M$ such that
$$DL_a(\varphi(0)):T_{\varphi(0)}M\rightarrow T_{\varphi(a)}M$$
is an euclidean isometry. Find the components $g_{ij}$ of $(M,\langle,\rangle)$.

My attempt:

The first thing I did was calculating the localization $f$ of $L_a$:
$$x\overset{\varphi}{\longmapsto}\varphi(x)\overset{L_a}{\longmapsto}\varphi(x+a)\overset{\varphi^{-1}}{\longmapsto}x+a$$
So $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ is defined by $f(x)=x+a$. Thus, the jacobian matrix of $f$ is the identity $I$ and it doesn't depend on the point $\varphi(x)$ nor $a$. Now I want to calculate $$g_{ij}=\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\vert_{\varphi(x)},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\vert_{\varphi(x)}\rangle_{\varphi(x)}$$
As we know that
$$DL_x(\varphi(0)):T_{\varphi(0)}M\rightarrow T_{\varphi(x)}M$$
is an euclidean isometry, then:
$$\langle u,v\rangle_{\varphi(0)}=\langle DL_x(\varphi(0))(u),DL_x(\varphi(0))(v)\rangle_{\varphi(x)}$$
for all $u,v\in T_{\varphi(0)}M$.

But the jacobian of the localization of the previous differential is the identity, so $DL_x(\varphi(0))(\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\vert_{\varphi(0)})=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\vert_{\varphi(x)}$, and we can conclude that:
$$g_{ij}=\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\vert_{\varphi(x)},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\vert_{\varphi(x)}\rangle_{\varphi(x)}=\langle\frac{\partial}{\partial x_i}\vert_{\varphi(0)},\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}\vert_{\varphi(0)}\rangle_{\varphi(0)}=\delta_{ij}$$

But this sounds strange for me. Any help or suggestions are welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems unnecessarily confusing to me. Since $\varphi^{-1}$ is a global chart, aren’t you just looking at its pullback of the standard metric on $\Bbb R^n$?

The pullback of the metric by the function $f\colon M\to\Bbb R^n$ is given by the formula
$$f^*\langle \cdot,\cdot \rangle (v,w) = \langle Df_p(v),Df_p(w)\rangle \quad\text{for tangent vectors }v,w\in T_pM.$$
Here $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ is the standard inner product on $\Bbb R^n$. In particular, if you work in the chart $f$ on $M$, by definition you will have $g_{ij}=\delta_{ij}$ for all $i,j$ at every point.

Comment: Don’t know what the pullback of a metric is. What I tried to do was to use the information of the problem to calculate explicitly the inner product at an arbitrary point, just because the inner product defined in the problem, seems to depend on the point. Would you explain me what you meant?

Answer (score 0):

I think that that is exactly the answer. You are prescribing a scalar product in the tangent space at point $\varphi(0)$ whose local expression is $\delta_{ij}$.
Then, you are applying a transitive family of diffeomorphisms $L_a$ and prescribing in every point the scalar product that these diffeomorphisms induce. Since in local coordinates they are translations, what you obtain is logical and coherent. The differential map is $dL_a=Id$ in local coordinates, so the coordinate expression for the induced scalar product is $\delta_{ij}$.